# Is it possible to 'unplace' annotations?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, editing, annotation

Is it possible to add or return annotations to the Unplaced Annotation list? Is there no way to put an annotation in the list once the annotation is placed?

I have noticed that the Aviation Editing toolbar has the option to hide annotation features, but there does not appear to be a button to add annotations back to the Unplaced Annotation list in the regular editing toolbar.

Using a definition query would be a last resort as there are lots of labels. Creating a layer from selected features and editing those would be a better option, but it would be nice to be able to place and unplace annotations in an editing session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return annotation to Unplaced you just simply change the field in attributes. It should have a default domain assigned to it for Placed and Unplaced.  When you select Unplaced it will disappear from your map but remain in the feature class.